# Immediately Invoked Function Expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, parentheses, iife

What is the reason of putting ( ) in the end for Immediately Invoked Function Expression in javascript

```
(function() {
    // Code that runs in your function
})( /* this parenthesis in the end */ )
```

Comment: the reason is your title, invoke a no name function

Comment: A function **call** looks like `referenceToFunction()`, so the trailing `()` are what make the function be invoked.

Comment: To...invoke the expression. Immediately. Without it it's just a function expression.

Comment: as you need to invoke it.

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry I am a novice Javscript programmer. Could you explain more on the fact that if I omit the parenthesis at the end, is it still syntactically correct to have the IIFE ?

Comment: @Pointy I am a little unclear on how the invocation takes place with the trailing (). Any direction which you can give me on this would be helpful.

Comment: yes it is correct but you don t have a reference to it hence you will never be able to find it/call it and at some point the garbage collector will get rid of it

Comment: @user2303712 if you omit the parentheses in the end *it's not an IIFE*. It's not immediately invoked. `(function(){})` is a simple function expression that defines a function and....does nothing with it, then throws it away without ever executing it.

Comment: The *value* of a function instantiation expression is a reference to the instantiated function.

Comment: If you leave end Parentheses alone, it seems like put the brand new desert island on the earth that you couldn't callback because you just set the anonymous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **Immediately Invoked Function Expression** is a:

`(function() { ... })` ← **Function Expression** which is **Immediately Invoked** → `()`

To elaborate, `(function() { ... })` is merely *defining* the function, and a function which is defined but never called is doing absolutely nothing.

In order for the code in the function to be executed, it needs to be *invoked* (often referred to as *calling* the function). That is why you wrap the function definition in parentheses (making it an expression that evaluates to a reference to the function) and then *immediately invoke* (or call) the function with any arguments `()` - or no arguments as in your sample.

It is more or less equivalent to doing this:

```
const someFunc = (function() { ... }); //merely assigns a function, the code inside doesn't run
someFunc(); //invokes the function (but in this case it isn't immediate)
```

except in this case you've bound the function reference to a variable and so it is no longer an IIFE.

Comment: It's worth noting that simply `(function() { ... })` won't actually do *anything* that you could ever observe - as it's a function expression that isn't even assigned to a variable or object property. Much like just eg `(2)` on its own on a line of code won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Klaycon for the detail.  This is my understanding now.        this is a function definition `function() { ... }`  If I want to call this function I have to wrap it in parenthesis `(    function() { ... }   )` Anytime you wrap something in parenthesis it becomes an expression and then if I want to immediately invoke it I have to add another parenthesis at the end `(    function() { ... }   ) ( )`. Let me know if I am correctly understanding it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks for that explanation. I am not able to wrap my head around the fact that just adding an extra parenthesis ` ( function() { ... } ) ( /*extra parenthesis*/ ) `will invoke function expression. Any simpler examples would be really helpful.

Comment: @user2303712 Imagine you define a function and assign it to some variable, like this: `var myFunc = function() { ... };`. Has the code represented by the `...` run yet? No. You've only defined a function, you haven't called it. What would you write to call the above function `myFunc`?

Comment: But that's exactly how you invoke any function value. You always need to put parentheses after the function value - sometimes with arguments inside, but not if the function needs no arguments - in order to execute it. That doesn't change if the function is given as an inline function expression.

Comment: @Klaycon Thanks a million for this ! I am going to be calling it by `myFunc();` And I have just added a parenthesis right there which is why we are adding a parenthesis for IIFE in the end. Did I understand that correctly ?

Comment: @user2303712 Exactly. You call a function by writing something that resolves to a function reference (like a variable which contains a function) on the left and the arguments you'll pass to the function in parentheses on the right. Left - `myFunc`. Right - `()`. It's the same for an IIFE, but the left side is that weird glob of parentheses and brackets since its a function expression.

Comment: @RobinZigmond These concepts are easy for you but I get stuck on them when I am understanding javascript and I really appreciate all your help. So having a parenthesis with no arguments means it does not need any but we have invoked the function by supplying empty parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason is purely syntactical. The JavaScript parser has to be able
> to easily differentiate between function declarations and function
> expressions. If we leave out the parentheses around the function
> expression, and put our immediate call as a separate statement
> **function(){}(3)**, the JavaScript parser will start processing it, and will conclude, because it’s a separate statement starting with the
> key- word function, that it’s dealing with a function declaration.
>
> Because every function declaration has to have a name (and here we
> didn’t specify one), an error will be thrown. To avoid this, we place
> the function expression within parentheses, signaling to the
> JavaScript parser that it’s dealing with an expression, and not a
> statement. There’s also an alternative way of achieving the same goal:

```
  (function(){}(3))
```

> By wrapping the immediate function definition and call within
> parentheses, you can also notify the JavaScript parser that it’s
> dealing with an expression.
>
> Those four expressions  are variations of the same theme of
> immediately invoked function expressions often found in various
> JavaScript libraries:

```
+function(){}();
-function(){}();
!function(){}();
~function(){}();
```

> This time, instead of using parentheses around the function
> expressions to differentiate them from function declarations, we can
> use unary operators: + , - , ! , and ~ . We do this to signal to the
> JavaScript engine that it’s dealing with expressions and not
> statements.

[Reference: johnresig.com/](https://johnresig.com/)